# Can tbl_summary() be customized to display significance stars to the footer?

Tags: r, gtsummary

The gtsummary package in R has a new neat function add_significance_stars() which adds significance stars to coefficient estimates with small p-values in regression models.  However, this function can only operate on tbl_regression or tbl_uvregression objects.

Is there a similar method that can be applied to a table_summary object so that p-value stars notate significant summary statistics?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gtsummary)
```

This is a table_summary object with p-values displayed in a column.

```
mtcars %>% 
     select(gear, mpg, disp, hp, wt) %>% 
     tbl_summary(by = "gear") %>% 
     add_p()
```

table_summary object

[image]

This is a tbl_regression object with p-values displayed in the desired fashion in the footer

```
mtcars %>% 
     select(gear, mpg, disp, hp, wt) %>% 
     lm(formula = gear ~ mpg + disp + hp + wt) %>% 
     tbl_regression(intercept = TRUE) %>%
     add_significance_stars()
```

tbl_regression object

[image]

Comment: Where do the stars go? Just on the pvalue?

Comment: I'm interested in having the stars notate the summary statistic that is significant.  I clarified this point in the above question.

Comment: So, in the example above, you want stars in every cell with summary statistics? Or, are you looking to add the stars just to the variable name?

Answer (score 4):

The purpose of `add_estimate_stars()` is to replace the p-values with stars. If you'd like to add stars to p-values in a `tbl_summary()`, you can define a function that appends stars to significant p-values.  Example below!

```r
library(gtsummary)
packageVersion("gtsummary")
#> [1] '1.4.0'

fmt_pvalue_with_stars <- function(x) {
  dplyr::case_when(
    x < 0.001 ~ paste0(style_pvalue(x), "***"),
    x < 0.01 ~ paste0(style_pvalue(x), "**"),
    x < 0.05 ~ paste0(style_pvalue(x), "*"),
    TRUE ~ style_pvalue(x)
  )
}

tbl <-
  mtcars %>%
  select(am, hp, cyl) %>%
  tbl_summary(by = am) %>%
  add_p(pvalue_fun = fmt_pvalue_with_stars) %>%
  modify_footnote(p.value ~ "*p<0.05; **p<0.01; ***p<0.001")
```

[image]
<sup>Created on 2021-04-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>